# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXX: Can not execute Sonar: 26721

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using JENKINS 1.574, sonar.maven.version=2.0, JDK1.8. Sonar Build failed throwing below error -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: Can not execute Sonar: 26721 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: Can not execute Sonar


at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at 

org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26721

Thankyou !!!
```

Comment: Which version of SonarQube do you run?

Comment: Thankyou for response. running SonarQube version 3.4.1

Comment: Sounds very old...I would suggest to use a newer version of sonar-maven-plugin...take a look at SonarQube...

Comment: I plan to upgrade sonar-maven-plug into 2.6,Do need SonarQube server to be upgraded from 3.4.1 to latest or SonarQube plug-in serves the issue? Could you please clarify. I am very sorry if asking at ground level as i still at learning of this area